# SQL script to get the existing database and it objects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to recreate the existing database with all the objects in it without data with different name. I can do this by Right Click on the database Task and then Generate script. But I want to automate this process. So is there any SQL approach to generate the entire database schemas without data.

Comment: If you don't want to do it that way, you could get all the definitions of your objects out of your source control software. Otherwise then the Generate Scripts tool is actually very handy.

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis, I came to know through SQL query we can't achieve this, but with the help of SQLpackage.exe we can achieve it.

**Approach 1:** Calling SQLPacakge.exe in PowerShell script. [Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4664/copy-a-sql-server-database-with-just-the-objects-and-no-data/)

**Approach 2** Using SQLPackage.exe in the command line. [Link](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/10/25/schema-only-backup-or-schema-only-db-copy/)

I have tried both the approaches, both work fine. Since I have some restrictions over PowerShell usage I went with Approach 2.